# Pipe blocking the function

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pipe

recently i have been working with Pipe and raspberry pi. I am trying to send a signal to my function to kill it however the "pipe.recv" is blocking the function. The signal is sent however the while loop doesnt get executed.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time
import os
import signal

def start(pipe):
    pipe1 = pipe[1].recv()
    while True:
       print('hello world')
    os.kill(pipe1,signal.SIGTERM)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn1 = Pipe()
    a = Process(target = start,args = (conn1,))
    a.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    print("TIMES UP")
    conn1[1].send(a.pid)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending, and attempting to retrieve the item from the same end of the pipe. Try this, where `pipe[0]` and `pipe[1]` are named to `parent` and `child`, for readability, instead:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time
import os
import signal

def start(child):
    pipe1 = child.recv()
    while True:
       print('hello world')
    os.kill(pipe1,signal.SIGTERM)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent, child = Pipe()
    a = Process(target = start,args = (child,))
    a.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    print("TIMES UP")
    parent.send(a.pid)
```

Comment: This is not working. The code ignores the signal and continues to execute the loop

Comment: @TommySony ofcourse the loop will never end, it's a while loop without an exit condition. Your original question was about why the loop is **not** executing, it does so now. If you don't want to create a never ending loop then don't use `while True` and specify an exit condition (I am not sure why you have the loop there in the first place).